# Pseudocode to actual code of linear fibonacci

Tags: c++, c++17

We are trying to convert this pseudocode into an actual code. The pseudo code is

```
Algorithm LinearFibonacci(k):
Input: A nonnegative integer k
Output: Pair of Fibonacci numbers (Fk,Fk−1)
if k ≤ 1 then
return (k,0)
else
(i, j)← LinearFibonacci(k−1)
return (i+ j, i)
```

I tried to translate it and came up with this

```
pair<int,int> LinearFibonnaci(int k) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    if (k <= 1) {
        return make_pair(k, 0);
    }
    else {
        make_pair(i, j) = LinearFibonnaci(k - 1);
        return make_pair(i + j, i);
    }
}
```

Am i doing this corretly because im not sure how to print out a pair function?

Comment: `make_pair(i, j) = LinearFibonnaci(k - 1);` won't work.  `tie(i,j) = LinearFibonnaci(k - 1);` should be better. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) for a description of `std::tie`

Comment: how can you print out the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) *object* (not function) has two public members, `first` and `second`.

Since C++11, you can also extract an element from a pair using [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/get).

See the following examples (testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AXtkyaeAmQlDrYPB)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

std::pair<int, int> LinearFibonnaci(int k);

int main()
{
    int k = 3;
    // Explicitly declaring the type
    std::pair<int, int> f = LinearFibonnaci(k);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
    std::cout << "F(" << k << ") = "
        << f.first << ",  F(" << (k - 1) << ") = " << f.second << '\n';
//         ^^^^^^^                                    ^^^^^^^^    

    k = 4;
    // Since C++11: Using 'auto' let the compiler deduce the type
    auto g = LinearFibonnaci(k);
//  ^^^^    
    std::cout << "F(" << k << ") = "
        << g.first << ",  F(" << (k - 1) << ") = " << g.second << '\n';
//         ^^^^^^^                                    ^^^^^^^^

    k = 5;
    // Since C++17: Structured binding declaration
    // See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding
    auto [n, m] = LinearFibonnaci(k);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^
    std::cout << "F(" << k << ") = " << n << ",  F(" << (k - 1) << ") = " << m << '\n';
//                                     ^^^                                  ^^^

    k = 8;
    // Since C++11: std::tie
    // See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie
    std::tie(n, m) = LinearFibonnaci(k);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
    std::cout << "F(" << k << ") = " << n << ",  F(" << (k - 1) << ") = " << m << '\n';
//                                     ^^^                                  ^^^

    k = 12;
    // Since C++11: std::get
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/get
    auto h = LinearFibonnaci(k);
    std::cout << "F(" << k << ") = " << std::get<0>(h)
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              << ",  F(" << (k - 1) << ") = " << std::get<1>(h) << '\n';
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

}

std::pair<int, int> LinearFibonnaci(int k)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    if (k <= 1) {
        return {k, 0};  // You can use the constructor, here
    }
    else {
        std::tie(i, j) = LinearFibonnaci(k - 1);     
        return {i + j, i};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As this question is marked C++17, [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) (`auto[i,j]`) can be used.

Another thing is that by using curly braces we can directly initialize the `std::pair` return object.

```
std::pair<int,int> LinearFibonnaci(int k) {
    if (k <= 1)
    {
        return {k, 0};
    }
    else
    {
        auto[i, j] = LinearFibonnaci(k - 1);
        return {i + j, i};
    }
}
```

To get the result, again structured bindings can be used to retrieve the values:

```
auto[i, j] = LinearFibonnaci(x);
```